# Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Bluetooth adapter NOT FOUND

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, atheros

### Input

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; lsmod | grep blue
```

### Result

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [144d:410e]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [144d:c652]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d57:ad04 Xenta 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2232:1029 Silicon Motion WebCam SC-13HDL11939N
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    1.392827] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    2.310376] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x350f00)
[    2.433225] usb 2-1.4: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   29.601435] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   29.601452] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   29.601455] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   29.601458] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   29.601464] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   46.175790] usb 2-1.4: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   46.177415] Bluetooth: hci0: don't support firmware rome 0x1020200
[   46.414734] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   46.414737] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   46.414741] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.480440] Bluetooth: hci0: don't support firmware rome 0x1020200
```

bluetooth             520192  11 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel

**Edit 1:** After the reinstall Ubuntu
Output is

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; lsmod | grep blue
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [144d:410e]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1d57:ad04 Xenta 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1029 Silicon Motion WebCam SC-13HDL11939N
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    1.344675] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    2.192358] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x350f00)
[    2.453024] usb 2-1.4: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   11.996298] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   11.996317] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.996322] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.996324] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.996330] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.257766] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2003 tx timeout
[   16.261695] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x201c tx timeout
[   18.265558] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1002 tx timeout
[   20.269484] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[   33.460055] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   33.460058] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   33.460061] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

bluetooth             520192  11 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel

**Edit 2 :** Out put for `hciconfig -a`

`hci0:  Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 20:16:D8:39:59:1A  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:197286 acl:27 sco:3812 events:179 errors:0
    TX bytes:198839 acl:30 sco:3813 commands:96 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Can't read local name on hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

**Edit3:** `$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 20:16:D8:39:59:1A dadarox-300E4C-300E5C-300E7C [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49984/discussion-on-question-by-abhijeet-manorma-madhav-qualcomm-atheros-ar9485-blueto).